# Creating Mac Image on PC

Tags: windows-7, macos

I have Logic Audio 9 for Mac on disks. I would like to install on my new MBP which has no CD Drive. How can I burn the disks to an image on my Windows machine so they work on my Mac?

Comment: Copy the content of the CD from your PC (that does have DVD drive), and transfer it across from the PC to the Mac using USB Disk / over the network?

Comment: Your Mac should be able to read any standard format data or audio CD. CD formatting standards aren't defined by Apple or Microsoft.